# Saving application settings in a SharePoint application best practices

Tags: best-practices

What are the best practices for saving application settings in a Sharepoint application?

Would anyone save the settings in the web.config's appsettings?

What about saving them in a SharePoint list?

Any other ideas? pros? cons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a list that I compiled with six different ways (and a few alternatives in the discussions).

[Six ways to store settings in SharePoint](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Six-ways-to-store-settings-in-SharePoint.aspx)

Comment: hey thats a **good** blog post right there! Added to delicious :-)

Comment: thanx- The property bag option is getting more interesting now with SP2010 and upgradeable features!

Answer (score 7):

As is often the case when developing with SharePoint, the answer is really "it depends"!

If you are configurating webparts, often the best way to configure them are using custom properties and either use UI or .webpart xml file to configure them.

If we are talking connection strings for InfoPath, theres [data connection libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772101.aspx)

Connection strings could be stored in web.config connectionstring settings, but could also be stored in the property bag for a site or a list: [SPPropertyBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sppropertybag%5Fmethods.aspx).

For features you can store properties in the feature xml. Example [here](http://vspug.com/tonstegeman/2006/06/28/setting-site-properties-in-a-sharepoint-2007-site-definition-by-using-a-feature/).

For timerjobs you can store it in the object itself, since it per definition is a [persisted object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.sppersistedobject.aspx) and hence stored in the persisted configuration cache. See an example [here](http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Robin/archive/2008/09/10/i%E2%80%99d-wish-i-knew-about-the-sppersistedobject-a-bit-earlier-.aspx) and [here](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/05/17/custom-timer-jobs-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0-where-to-store-configuration.aspx) how to store this kind of data.

As you can see it is not easy to give one general answer to your question :-)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not remotely biased of course, but I think [my Config Store solution](http://spconfigstore.codeplex.com) is a good option (based on storing config values in a list). In addition to what I list on the codeplex site, there are [some later enhancements](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/01/better-config-store-for-sharepoint.html) such as allowing hierarchical config and providing an expression builder for use in ASPX markup, so it has a lot of features which can be useful. It's unlikely to be the right choice for every scenario, but if a list seems like the right approach it should be a much better starting point than nothing due to things like the caching layer.

Suggest also checking out [Microsoft's SharePoint Patterns & Practices Guidance](http://spg.codeplex.com) on this - in the PDF they have a good table comparing some options (they also mention my Config Store solution, but I promise that's not the only reason I think it's good info!)

Comment: So you think just because you wrote it you deserve the votes do ya?  I got here first buddy... ;-)

Comment: LOL :) Psst, I'll cut you in, don't worry about it!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you take a look at Chris O'Brien's SharePoint Config Store:

http://www.codeplex.com/SPConfigStore

Answer (score 3):

Generally, my "rule-of-thumb" is that if it is "application (site) specific" then store it in a list.  If it is something that needs to be "tuned" by an administrator rarely and applies to multiple "applications" then store it in the "web.config".

One thing, if you do store settings in a list - ensure versioning is turned on - I just had a situation where a vendor was blaming my team for making changes - we did not, heck at the time we did not even know their settings were stored in a list.